# How do I automatically send data from an azure sql server to a windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, azure

I want the service to automatically send data to the phone when a row on a particular table is updated, how do I do this?

Comment: start by looking at the Synch framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753

Comment: Can you provide more details? Would you like to receive push notifications too, or just have this happen when your application is running? Perhaps some sort of long-polling would let you achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1)
Create an application on your phone that supports push notifications.

Step 2)
Create a webservice (inside Azure) that you send your notification token and uri to plus some type of message that contains the stuff you want to monitor. Store that subscription somewhere, azure tables comes to mind.

Step 3)
have a worker role monitor the Azure database and the azure table of subscriptions to send out updates to your phone.

Monitoring for changes can be done in a number of ways, Sync framework is one of them. But it might be easier to use a a service + queue to isolate access to Sql Azure and then automatically send the push message to the phone if needed.